# No module named twilio found while working with azure functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, twilio, azure-functions

Below is the code,

```
import logging
import json, os
import azure.functions as func
import twilio
import twilio.rest
from twilio.rest import Client
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    filename = logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
             #f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
             #f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    filename = logging.info(myblob.name)
    print(filename)     #output - teamaudio/22108192-9a74-4b6e-a237.wav
    fname = filename.split("/")[1]
    print(fname)
    client = Client(account_sid,auth_token)
```

Error : No module named twilio found when we trigger azure functions

Please guide on how to import twilio, twilio.rest in azure functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the dependencies , do you have requirement.txt which contains the dependencies?

Otherwise you can open Kudu and manually install the dependency using pip install [twillio](https://sajeetharan.com/2020/01/10/want-to-alert-your-employees-to-have-a-break-at-work-azure-function-can-help-you/).

Comment: How can we do in azure functions? In local env it works

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan. I solved this by adding the modules in requirements.txt

Comment: Trying to use from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, getting the error "No module named _speech_py_impl in azyre functions... Seams like we need to install sudo apt-get install libasound2.. How can we do in azure functions?